# What is the meaning of "zen is the art of being at one with the two'ness"

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases

> zen is the art of being at one with the two'ness

What's the *being at one*?
What's the *two'ness*?
Why *two'ness* not *twoness*?

I just don't know the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: Is iy me only, or should it be "Zen is the art of 'being at one with the two' ness

Comment: @Ham: Iys just you.

Comment: A large amount of "Zen is" statements are designed to make no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of these "Zen is the art of..." phrases, and their quality and applicability varies widely.  Some are profound, and actually express truths about Zen; some are jokey and mock-profound (like this one); some are marketing catchphrases or outright parody.

The whole Zen/art meme comes from a book, *[Zen in the Art of Archery](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375705090)*, published in 1948, which was among the first popular introductions of Zen to Europe and the West.  As famous and popular as that book was, it was overshadowed (in the US, anyway) by the 1974 *[Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553277472)* (which is famously neither about Zen nor art nor motorcycle maintenance, but which I highly recommend nonetheless!)  Between those two books, the connection between "Zen" and "the art of (x)" has been pretty firmly established in the collective unconscious.

"**[To be at one with](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_one_with)** something" means to be completely comfortable with (something) / to understand (something) so profoundly that you feel that there are no barriers between you and it.  The usual usage is "at one with the Universe" / "at one with the world".  (This phrase is the basis of [the Dalai Lama joke that's been in the news lately](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30244/can-someone-please-explain-this-dalai-lama-joke-to-me).)

There's no such word as **two'ness**; if there were such a word it probably shouldn't have an apostrophe in the middle (so it should have been **twoness**.)  Adding "**-ness**" to the end of another word is a common way of inventing a new word; like "twoness", if the meaning wasn't clear from the context, there's no point in looking in a dictionary because it won't be there.

I don't know what the context was where you saw this phrase, but I'm guessing that the writer had just been talking about duality, or the number 2, or...  Tossing in a phrase like "Zen is the art of being at one with the twoness" was most likely the author trying to be funny while also emphasizing the importance of 2 (in whatever context he was talking about in the first place.)

Authors, take note: if you're trying to explain a concept, don't invent words and put them in silly mock-profound philosophical phrases and drop the whole thing into your book/article/whatever.  It might make a few people laugh, but it's more likely to make a lot of people confused.

### Edit:

This phrase may also have been influenced by a Woody Allen line: "Students achieving Oneness will move on to Twoness."

Comment: Although not widely accepted as a "real" dictionary, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twoness) defines **twoness** as: *The state of being two; duality.*

Comment: Looks to be the signature of the moderator "feline" [here](http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=7682).

Comment: @rintaun - I'll have to add Wiktionary to the list of places I check for neologisms.

Comment: @Callithumpian - Good catch!  Sometimes the signatures that people choose for themselves on fora just make me shake my head.  I wonder whether "feline" even remembers what it meant, or why it seemed so profound when s/he chose it...

Comment: @MT_Head, wordnik has it too - http://www.wordnik.com/words/twoness

Comment: @rintaun, @Unreason - Woody Allen used it in a fairly famous quote - I'll edit my answer to reflect that.  I still call BS on it as a "real" word, but it does pass my internal descriptivist test (i.e. when you see the word, you know what it means; also, it doesn't violate any rules of grammar or construction.)