# What is the meaning of expression "zen and the art of.."

Tags: meaning, expressions

Over the years I have come across a bunch of book titles and blog posts that goes "Zen and the art of X", and X being any damn thing. What to deduct when you see such a title?

My research lead me to [this question,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/what-is-the-meaning-of-zen-is-the-art-of-being-at-one-with-the-twoness) but it is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: The answer to that question you linked to shows you the source of the meme: Pirsig's *Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance*.

Comment: @Robusto - that's worthy of being an answer. Some folks are not old enough to remember a world before that book.

Comment: @Kate Gregory: Hmm. I only have to type **zen a**, and Google autocompletes the entire title as its top suggestion (other suggestions include title + *quotes, review,* etc.). It's general reference **and** a duplicate. Not quite as bad as asking ["Who are the Beatles"](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1340891/Judge-James-Pickles-said-didnt-know-The-Beatles-dies-aged-85.html), but hardly much better.

Comment: "deduct" is not "deduce" ...

Comment: First of all, that answer does not tell what the usage actually means. It just tells you that the usage was introduced in book title.

Comment: @ring bearer: What is the sound of one hand clapping? And what does it mean? Read the book, or if you don't have time, read a review of it.

Answer (score 2):

Zen is a way of thinking, steeped in Eastern mysticism and philosophy.  *Zen and the Art of X* simply applies Zen thought to whatever X is.  In the case of *Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance*, the book is a story of the author's cross-country motorcycle trip, heavily peppered with Zen musings.

It's hard to define Zen concisely - it's rather abstract and elusive.  I did find [this list of quotes](http://environ.okstate.edu/staff/wfocht/Porch_12.pdf) related to Zen.  (If you read through that list, you might get at least a rudimentary introduction to Zen thought).